# How can I spawn multiples spheres at random positions [a-frame]

Tags: random, aframe

In `aframe` I want to spawn a `sphere` 100 times, each at a random `position`

First, each value in `position= "x y z"` should a number between -100 and 100

```
<a-sphere          
     position="x y z"
     radius="0.5">
</a-sphere>
```

Second, the code above should be repeated 100 times, the leaving the previous `sphere` unaffected.

This is the desired [end result](https://i.giphy.com/media/5xtDarHj0ORdxfWtV6g/giphy.webp), ignoring the motion.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

- http://ngokevin.github.io/kframe/components/entity-generator/
- https://ngokevin.github.io/kframe/components/randomizer/

Uses entity-generator + randomizer components.

```
<a-mixin id="sphere" geometry="primitive: sphere" material random-position="min: -100 -100 -100; max: 100 100 100"></a-mixin>
<a-entity entity-generator="mixin: sphere; num: 100"></a-entity>
```